# Django - Foreign key, admin and forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I’m working on a Django Project (i’m a beginner) and i have a small problem. I have different model with Foreign_Key. And also I have Forms to implements model.

My problem, is not to big i think : I want the id + name instance on my admin or on my forms. Actually i have the value in

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

I can’t do `return self.id` because it’s Int type.

example of my models.py

```
class Affaires(models.Model):
id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
adresse = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
cp = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
ville = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
dessinateur = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
conducteur = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
chefdeprojet = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
cloture = models.IntegerField()


class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'affaires'

def __str__(self):
    return self.nom
```

Have you got an idea ?
[image: Example of my admin]

[image: Example of a form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these attributes as values to string placeholders:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.id, self.nom)
```